# Ghostscript keeps a lock on separations in x64 mode

Tags: c#, ghostscript, adobe-illustrator

I'm using Ghostscript's DLL (gsdll[32|64].dll) to process TIFF separations of Adobe Illustrator files. My code is in C# .NET and running in Windows.

For background information, I'm using the "tiffsep" device to create TIFFs of each plate, then converting them into JPGs via GDI for display in the UI.

**The problem is that, when using the 64-bit DLL, Ghostscript retains locks on *some* of the separations**. This is the code I'm using the call the DLL:

```cs
private static void ExecuteGs64(string[] args)
{
    IntPtr instancePtr;
    lock (instanceLock)
    {
        NativeMethods.CreateAPIInstance64(out instancePtr, IntPtr.Zero);
        try
        {
            int result = NativeMethods.InitAPI64(instancePtr, args.Length, args);
            if (result < 0)
            {
                throw new ExternalException("Ghostscript conversion error " + result, result);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // according to GS docs, this should clean up any memory used
            NativeMethods.ExitAPI64(instancePtr);
            NativeMethods.DeleteAPIInstance64(instancePtr);
        }
    }
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("gsdll64.dll", EntryPoint = "gsapi_new_instance")]
    internal static extern int CreateAPIInstance64(out IntPtr pinstance, IntPtr caller_handle);

    [DllImport("gsdll64.dll", EntryPoint = "gsapi_init_with_args")]
    internal static extern int InitAPI64(IntPtr instance, int argc, string[] argv);

    [DllImport("gsdll64.dll", EntryPoint = "gsapi_exit")]
    internal static extern int ExitAPI64(IntPtr instance);

    [DllImport("gsdll64.dll", EntryPoint = "gsapi_delete_instance")]
    internal static extern void DeleteAPIInstance64(IntPtr instance);
}
```

I'm running this using the following arguments:

```
-q -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dEPSCrop -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=0 -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sDEVICE=tiffsep -r150x150 -sOutputFile=[OutPath] [InPath]
```

The code runs, and GS generates the separations. However, some of the separations are still locked by the application (I've tried taking the GS code out of the main application and running it inside a test console app with nothing else going on, same result). These locks are held until the application stops.

For me, this is a problem, because the GS call needs to be made as part of a larger workflow, and the files that it generates require further processing and eventual cleanup which can't happen until the locks are released.

To give an example:

```
Original file: BGL1100001A01.ai

Outputs (L denotes which files are locked):

[ ] BGL1100001A01(Black).tif
[L] BGL1100001A01(Cutter Guide).tif
[ ] BGL1100001A01(Cyan).tif
[ ] BGL1100001A01(Magenta).tif
[L] BGL1100001A01(PANTONE 143 C).tif
[L] BGL1100001A01(PANTONE 201 C).tif
[L] BGL1100001A01(PANTONE 360 C).tif
[L] BGL1100001A01(PANTONE 485 C).tif
[L] BGL1100001A01(PANTONE 488 C).tif
[L] BGL1100001A01(Spot White).tif
[ ] BGL1100001A01(Yellow).tif
[L] BGL1100001A01.tif
```

This is confirmed by procexp.exe:

[image: Screengrab of procexp.exe, showing locks on the files]

For some reason, it doesn't lock on the CMYK plates, but it does on everything else.

**Here's the weird thing: it doesn't do this in 32-bit mode!**

If I use gsdll32.dll, everything works fine and no locks are held. Unfortunately, I need to run this in 64-bit mode.

I started by using the DLLs from GS 9.07 (latest from their website); in desperation I've downloaded and re-compiled them from source, but exactly the same thing is happening.

**I will love you forever if you have any help to give!!!**

Comment: Why this question is labeled as "C++"?

Comment: Ghostscript is written in C++, and it might be the case that I have to recompile it to change its behaviour.

Comment: Ghostscript is written in C in fact. I would suggest you open a bug report for this.

Comment: Doh! Yes, my bad, untagged. I've filed a report on their bug tracker, but I had a tiny hope that there was something I was missing.

Comment: FWIW...

I'm using GS 9.18 on Win7, with a C# x64 build, and experiencing a similar "output file is locked longer than it ought to be" snag, although I'm using the 'pnggray' device.

I checked the tracker and found http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=694859 which looks like a good match, but there doesn't appear to be any activity on it since early 2014.

I'm not too fussed for now, since I'm using temp files for conversions, and temp files get cleaned up elsewise at times. \*shrug\*